# Comma delimited but need to exclude an enclosed field filled with comma's

Tags: bash, awk

I have a CSV data file say with 5 columns separated by comma.

```
c1, c2, col3, c4, c5
stack, over, upon, true, yes
ab, zy, pq,rs,tu,vw,ef, four, ivef
```

Viewing the csv file in Excel will clearly show those 5 columns, and the 3rd field having the following values: pq,rs,tu,vw,ef.

However, how do I get awk to print out col3 ($3) with "pq,rs,tu,vw,ef" as output. Right now, it sees it as pq. And the rest have shifted out of place.

---

Updated csv sample:

```
Movie ID,Remit ID,Property ID,Movie Uploader,Channel ID,Channel Display Name,Video Title,Views Count,Status,Claim Origin,Claim Type,Is Affiliate Uploaded,Is Premium,Reference Movie ID,Policy,Applied Policy,Claim Date,Movie Upload Date,Custom ID,EWRC,Title,Authors,Notes,Asset Labels
G4pelo5M9XI,ka-9foAPFkg,N103145385208693,originalkaraoke,UCnF6KQeanPgBRyEMeFmrNnA,Karaoke,Motel Fornia - Karaoke,6702511,Active,Descriptive Search,AudioVisual,No,No,,,Block the following countries: US; Track in all countries except: US,2017/01/25,2011/12/30,fW1aUnBbwL8,,MOTEL FORNIA - BLOCK,,,
uZ94drkfB5c,WIMPvt22JY8,B103945385208693,,UCBa3saYRQTO8WzsKacgaJNQ,Best Songs Backing Tracks,"Motel Fornia - Bass Backing Track with scale, chords and lyrics",1913,Active,Descriptive Search,AudioVisual,No,No,,,Track in all countries except: US; Block the following countries: US,2017/01/25,2016/01/19,fW1aUqBzwL2,,MOTEL FORNIA - BLOCK,,,
2p1te0kAE2A,HMR7M2SjJJw,N103945385208693,,UCLAvPQhYyx8yUNMG0AkPYuw,Jordy Nalgas,HOSTEL NARNIA,751,Active,Descriptive Search,AudioVisual,No,No,,,Block the following countries: US; Track in all countries except: US,2017/01/25,2016/09/11,fW1dUnBhwL8,,HOSTEL NARNIA - BLOCK,,,
```

and we need to extract value of `Views Count` column.

Comment: If input really is `ab, zy, pq, rs, tu, vw, ef, four, ivef` then what makes `pq, rs, tu, vw, ef` a single column?

Comment: See this pastebin as an example -- https://pastebin.com/GUMDHpfc. I am interested in the Views Count column, which should be just integers. And to answer your question it should enclosed within double-quotes to make it a single column.

Comment: If `it should enclosed within double-quotes` then obviously show it `enclosed within double-quotes` in your question - don't show us sample input that doesn't match your actual input or you'll get a solution that doesn't do what you actually need. You've already had one person waste their time coming up with an answer based on the input you showed us and then having to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

In `gnu awk` you can use `FPAT` to tell awk what is a valid column expression.

You can use:

```
awk -v col='Views Count' -v FPAT='"[^"]*"|[^,]*' '
     NR==1{for (h=1; h<=NF; h++) if ($h == col) break; next} {print $h}' file.csv

6702511
1913
751
```

If you want column heading also then remove `next` from awk script above.